# Custom Button Class not resizing based on layout_weight android

Tags: android

I have a CircularMeter class which is derived from Button. The problem is that it is not resizing even if the weight given is 0.5 (ie. half the vertical screen).

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/WidgetDataLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <com.test.CircularMeter
            android:id="@+id/cm1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: post your full layout

Comment: android:layout_alignParentTop="true" is used RelaiveLayout 
weights are used in LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

You can take help from this example to make your circularmeter fill half of the vertical screen

eg.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#123456"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#123456"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no `layout_weight` in `CircularMeter`.

It's parent `LinearLayout` has both `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `android:layout_weight="0.5"` which is not correct since `layout_alignParentTop` is a layout attribute for a `RelativeLayout` parent while `android:layout_weight`is an attribute for a `LinearLayout` parent. The layout XML does not show what is the parent layout actually is. `android:layout_height="0dp"` would make the layout invisible unless there really is a vertical `LinearLayout` as a parent.

Also note that `layout_weight="0.5"` won't make the view size half the screen. After doing first pass layout for a linear layout, the weight mechanism just distributes any *remaining* space in *proportion* of element weights. By default an element's weight is 0. So if you have just one element with non-zero weight, it will get *all* remaining space in its linear layout parent.